# Selenium webdriver - unable to locate an element on youtube

Tags: java, selenium, youtube, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to retrieve the search results from YouTube suggestions using Selenium webdriver (Java) but i am getting the following error. Please help.

**Error:**

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"gssb_e"}
>
> Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
> System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.3', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
> Driver info: driver.version: unknown

**Code**

```
package test3;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class YoutubeSuggest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                
                // Go to the youtube home page
                driver.get("http://www.youtube.com/");
                
                // Enter the query string "Ozzy "
                WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("search_query"));
                query.sendKeys("Ozzy ");
                
                // Sleep until the div we want is visible or 10 seconds is over
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
                    WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));

                    // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
                    if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
                      break;
                    }
                }

                // And now list the suggestions
                List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gsq_a']"));
                
                for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
                    System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
                }

                //driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**HTML generated by youtube suggestions:**

```
<table dir="ltr" class="gstl_50 gssb_c"
    style="width: 585px; top: 39px; position: fixed; text-align: left; left: 230px; display: none;"
    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="gssb_f"></td>
            <td style="width: 100%;" class="gssb_e"><table class="gssb_m"
                    style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne crazy train</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne no more tears</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne mama i'm coming home</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne paranoid</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne justin bieber</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne mr crowley</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne bark at the moon</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne interview</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="">
                            <td style="text-align: left;" dir="ltr" class="gssb_a gsfs"><div
                                    class="gsq_a">
                                    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;"><span>ozzy<b>
                                                            osbourne dreamer</b></span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How on earth do you want to do that from UI level? Is there a reason you can't use [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started)?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to the code @ https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted, which works but the youtube suggestion isn't working. This is more for automation using web driver.

Comment: YouTube or even any Google based site, is just awful to use for site automation. I'd try something different, if all you are attempting to do is use WebDriver on *something*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below logic to get the youtube search results after loading URL .

```
driver.findElement(By.name("search_query")).sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver"+Keys.ENTER);
List<WebElement> search_result=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#results ol#search-results>li h3>a"));
for(WebElement each_result:search_result) {
   System.out.println(each_result.getAttribute("title"));
}
```

Comment: Hi Santhosh, could you please explain how you have managed to find elements using css selector condition "By.cssSelector("#results ol#search-results>li h3>a"". I am unable to find the css when I inspect search results on youtube. thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: By considering required element in page we need to inspect DOM after that we need to construct a locator to locate element(s) required. Refer below links. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/03/replace-xpath-with-css-selector.html

Answer (score 0):

it seems that since the time of writing the tutorial google has changed the element class names. The changes below worked for me.

```
WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("sbsb_a"));
```

```
 List allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='sbsb_c gsfs']"));
```